# Using regular expression to exclude a subfolder in c++

Tags: c++, regex, macos

I'd like to use regex to match this file path on macOS:

```
/Users/username/Library/Containers/com.tencent.xinWeChat/...
```

There are many levels of subfolders in this path, but I want to exclude this specific path.

```
/Users/username/Library/Containers/com.tencent.xinWeChat/Data/Library/Application Support/com.tencent.xinWeChat/2.0b4.0.9/8be628ba3eab5f8c52f6f1b22f897153/Message/MessageTemp/8be628ba3eab5f8c52f6f1b22f897153/OpenData/...
```

I want to exclude the path containing "OpenData" in the regex, so I use this one:

```
R"^/Users/[^/]+/Library/Containers/com\.tencent\.\w+/.+/(?!OpenData)/.+"
```

But it doesn't work. 
Negative lookahead is a little hard for me.
Could anybody show me the correct regex? Thanks!

Comment: Try `R"(^/Users/[^/]+/Library/Containers/com\.tencent\.\w+/(?!(?:.*/)?OpenData(?:/|$)).+)"`

Comment: I tried it on regex101, but it doesn't match this path.   /Users/username/Library/Containers/com.tencent.xinWeChat/Data/Library/Application Support/com.tencent.xinWeChat/2.0b4.0.9/8be628ba3eab5f8c52f6f1b22f897153/Message/MessageTemp/8be628ba3eab5f8c52f6f1b22f897153/Image/a.png

Comment: It does - https://regex101.com/r/UeUMOf/1. If you have trouble using online testers I recommend testing directly in the target environment, I provided the exact string literal to try in C++.

Comment: Hello, I have one more little question. I have no idea why this regex cannot match test string 1.   R"(^/Users/[^/]+/Library/Containers/com\.tencent\.\w+/(?!(?:[^/]+/)+OpenData(?:/)).+)"

Comment: Why one more? Did the previous one solve the current issue?

Comment: I just want the regex to be more specific instead of using .*. I thought [^/]+ would work, but it doesn't. But this one works.  R"(^/Users/[^/]+/Library/Containers/com\.tencent\.\w+/(?!(?:.+/)+OpenData(?:/)).+)"   Jeez, regex is a little hard for me.

Comment: The `(?:.+/)+` makes little sense as it is equal to `.+/`. `(?:/)` is equal to `/` as it does not match end of string any longer. You must use `R"(^/Users/[^/]+/Library/Containers/com\.tencent\.\w+/(?!(?:.*/)?OpenData(?:/|$)).+)"` or you have a different input than you showed in the question

Comment: I see. Can I just remove the |$ because "OpenData" would never be the end of a file path. There are definitely files or folders in it.

Comment: That information is missing in the question. You may do whatever you see fit with the regex, I can only suggest best generic pattern without knowing details that only you know. *the path containing "OpenData"* does not mean `OpenData` does not occur at the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try to learn more about regex.

Comment: I posted an answer below with explanations and demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^/Users/[^/]+/Library/Containers/com\.tencent\.\w+/(?!(?:.*/)?OpenData(?:/|$)).+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UeUMOf/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `/Users/`  - a literal substring
- `[^/]+` - 1+ chars other than `/`
- `/Library/Containers/com\.tencent\.` - a `/Library/Containers/com.tencent.` string
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `/` - a `/` char
- `(?!(?:.*/)?OpenData(?:/|$))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is an `OpenData` subpart in the URL
- `.+` - any 1+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.